# How can I pass an Object of a class that has nested classes within it to an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Let's say I have the following Class:

```
public class Person {

private String name;
private String phoneNumber;
.
.
.
private Address address;

}
```

Where Address is a different class. I want to pass an object of that class from one Activity to another in android, is that possible? and if so how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by changing your class so that it implements either [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) or [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). You can then add the object to a Bundle, and retrieve it from the intent you use to start the new activity.

```
// setup data
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putSerializable("my_key", personObject);
startActivity(intent);

// retrieve data in second activity
Person myPerson = getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("my_key");
```

Comment: And this way the nested objects will be present as well?

Comment: Any nested objects will also need to implement Serializable.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now.